# React setFocus on Input field - security?

Tags: reactjs, security, input, ref, setfocus

Question: In React I read that you should not use 'ref' and 'findDOMNode' for security reasons. (insecurely accessing native DOM Elements...)

Is there another way to set the focus manually in input fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
    function manualFocus() {
    document.getElementById("text").focus();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" id="text" name="text"></input>
      <input type="text2" id="text2" name="text2"></input>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => manualFocus()}>Manual Focus</button>
    </div>
  );
```